# store result set (when we have to return more than one column)into the variable in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I store my result set into the variable in MySql?
I don't want to use temp Table.
In the SQL sever we have table variable but I think we don't have it in MySQl.

I need something like table variable or pseudo-code can be something like this

```
SET @tbl =(SELECT  Name,
                LastName
        FROM    MyTBL  
        WHERE   Id = 1);
```

`SELECT Name FROM  @tbl;`

Comment: They Suggested use temp table. I mentioned that I don't to use temp table

Comment: Sorry, it's just not possible.  If you are only storing a single row, you can use multiple variables instead to store that data individually. However, if you want to store multiple columns and multiple rows in mysql, you have to use temp tables (even if you don't want to)...

Comment: Thank you @sgeddes I got my answer!